# The algorithm to draw and process the relationship coordinate between parent and child nodes as topology tree

Tags: javascript, algorithm, tree, topology, topological-sort

I have a data construction with the relationship of parent node and child node in JavaScript like this:

```
var data = {
    'name': 'A1',
    'children': [
        {
            'name': 'B1',
            'children': [
                {'name': 'C1'},
                {'name': 'C2'},
                {'name': 'C3'},
                {'name': 'C4'},
                {'name': 'C5'}
            ]
        },
        {
            'name': 'B2',
            'children': [
                {
                    'name': 'C6',
                    'children': [
                        {'name': 'D1'}
                    ]
                },
                {'name': 'C7'},
                {'name': 'C8'}
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

What I need to do is to calculate the coordinate of each child node with topology. The final result will be probably like this - The topology tree:

```
┌─────────────────────────────────
│                ┌C1[2,0]
│                │C2[2,1]
│       ┌B1[1,2]─┼C3[2,2]   
│       │        │C4[2,3]
│A1[0,4]┤        └C5[2,4]
│       │        ┌C6[2,5]─D1[3,5]
│       └B2[1,6]─┼C7[2,6]
│                └C8[2,7]
```

Of course, the algorithm can be compatible with various situation, like if the final node is with too much child nodes, the Y coordinate of each parent will plus a offset.

This is the demonstration of topology tree: http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html

But yet, I just want to the core of the JavaScript code to calculate the coordinate like above. Any idea? Or maybe you can use other language to achieve it.

Many thanks!